# Is it possible to make a user log out from the first browser while making log in from the another browser with the same credentials in identiyserver 4

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer 4 for the user authentication. What I want to achieve is that if the same user makes multiple log in from different browsers, he/she will be logged out from all of the previous browsers except the last browser. Many thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if you use server-side persistence of the authentication cookie. You can then invalidate any other sessions that exist for a given account provided you store the data in a manner that allows you to query easily by user ID.

Check out `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` and the `ITicketStore` interface for an idea of how it works.